# I can not install psycopg2 gives an error what to do

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, python-3.9

I can not install psycopg2 gives an error what to do I just started to study and already such traps help.

**Error:**

```
    File "C:\Users\МК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: tried it anyway it doesn’t work it may be that python 3.9 version is not compatible with psycopg2 version

Comment: Python 3.9 is less than a month old, so not every package will support it yet. The easiest solution might be to use `psycopg2-binary` with Python 3.8.X for now.

Comment: are there any other options?

Comment: If you must use Python 3.9, then you'll have to install `psycopg2` from source for now. I can't help you do that on Windows,